# Minimum size of a boot partition on debian

Tags: boot, partitioning, debian

I'm setting up an old box with Debian; what I'm aiming at is a very minimalistic system for a more or less educational purpose (just a router/proxy or a system with some network cards configured as a switch) and I want to use old hard drives I have idling around my drawers (500 MB ... 2 GB).

First etch (4.0), because this is the last version that still had boot floppies, then the box is to be upgraded to lenny (5.0) and squeeze (6.0).

Therefore, I will end up having a a couple of different kernel versions in the boot partition. If I don't want to be wasteful and if I end up needing a separate boot partition, how large should it be?

I've used 10 MB long ago, but that was woody (3.0) or sarge (3.1), and only one kernel in the boot partition, and this seems to be too small for what I want to do now.

(*I know that even 10 GB hard drives are obsolete and cost no money, but I'm really quite curious how much hardware is really needed to achieve something useful.*)

Comment: How big's the hard drive?

Comment: Maybe .5 to 2 GB; question has been edited to include this piece of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 3 kernels installed, and `/boot` is now at 43MB. 2 of them are stock Debian kernels and another is more custom and isn't a Debian kernel. That means that 20MB/kernel seems more than adequate.

Comment: Thanks. Especially for not just giving the number but also for mentioning how and where to look.